# How to iterate over all input hidden values using $.each

Tags: jquery

I want to do something with each hidden input value, so I coded the following javascript using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each($("input[type='hidden']"), function (index, value) {
    alert(value.val());
});
```

But I get he following execution error: `value.val is not a function.`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value in the iterating function is a Node, not a jQuery object.

You still need to go: `$(value).val();`

See the last example here: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 14):

This would work:

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
     $(this).val() //do something with
});
```

Comment: Just to add, there's also the `:hidden` pseudo selector, so `input:hidden` yields the same matches.

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure what karim79 has written here is correct. I believe input:hidden will select input elements which have been made invisible by virtue of CSS (for instance) and that's not the same as finding input elements of type hidden. The original question is a little ambiguous on what was wanted but I'm just mentioning it in case it's useful.